# Loss of quality when resizing an animated GIF

Tags: c#, imageresizer

I am trying to re-size an animated gif image from a stream. The image got resized but the result is not as I wished, the animation lost quality.
I am resizing from a stream(tried from a file path too). I have also changed the mode.
This below is my code.

```
ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Current.Build(
    filePhotoUpload.PostedFile.InputStream, 
    "~/images/test/uno.gif", 
    new ImageResizer.ResizeSettings("width=480;height=240;format=gif;mode=min"));
```

Other question. How can I specify the result to a stream. How to define the stream target?

Using an ASP.NET web form application.

Comment: If you have two questions, please post them as two separate questions -- you'll get much better answers that way.

Comment: This sounds promising http://imageresizing.net/plugins/prettygifs did you try it?

Comment: I suppose you want to go shopping for another product.  Do use the company's technical support channels before you give up.

Comment: I used AnimatedGifs plugins. But I will use prettygifs also. Just give me some minutes.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean when you say the "animation lost quality"? Did the colors turn out poorly? Did visual artifacts get introduced? Did the frame timing get lost? Ideally post an example so we can see what you're talking about.

Comment: These are the URL to the image source and image target:
http://www.naylornetwork.com/NaylorOVS/Images/source.gif
http://www.naylornetwork.com/NaylorOVS/Images/target.gif

Comment: Used prettygifs and IT WORKED!!. Will, I won't say thanks because it is prohibited here but... you know

Comment: Perhaps you should post that as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Will's suggestion I uploaded the PrettyGifs plugin from http://imageresizing.net/plugins/prettygifs, updated my web.config file `<plugins>` element with `<add name="PrettyGifs" />`  and voila!!.
Now, for the use of stream. This is how I resolved my second question.

```
var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Current.Build(filePhotoUpload.PostedFile.InputStream, ms, new ImageResizer.ResizeSettings("width=240;height=240;format=gif;mode=min"), false);
```

I was also concerned for the memory leak and started to do some tests but my time doesn't let me finish so I have none to say about it for now. But it is working.